# Fast Desktop Sharing Over LAN?

Tags: networking, vnc, remote, remote-access

I have a Macbook and a Windows Vista box hooked up to the same switch, I'd like to be able to remote into the Macbook from the Vista box, and get decent graphics.

Currently I'm using Vine Server for VNC and VNCViewer on Vista. This setup works well enough except that the graphics are somewhat choppy, especially when the dock is animating, or Windows are being minimized/maximized.

Is there any way to improve upon this?

Comment: get faster LAN equipment and network cards....

Comment: @00101010, if I could, I would vote down your answer. It is as unhelpful as it is obnoxious. I've seen this behaviour on gigabit equipment, since it's a failing of VNC, not the hardware.

Comment: my solution in this situation was to pick my iMac as the primary workstation (the bigger screen did it), and use Remote Desktop Connection to go into the Windows box. However, this may not be the right choice for you.

Comment: @Randolph you can flag my comment if you want but it is true... you need more throughput to get better quality and to get more throughput you need faster equipment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), it provides decent remote control and I use it constantly over the internet, which is usually slower than LAN speeds and get very good graphics rendering.

Comment: I've not used TeamViewer, but I'll give it a whirl now.

Comment: TeamViewer is based on UltraVNC it is useful if one or both parties are behind a router... it uses the TeamViewer servers as a 3rd party to establish the connection. If you are on the same LAN it would be better to use UltraVNC so you don't have to rely on the TeamViewer servers.

Comment: Previous comment is not completely true. [TeamViewer can be used within a local network only](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/help/40-can-teamviewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-lan-only)